# How to do hyperparameter tuning in Detectron2

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, keypoint, detectron

Detectron2
COCO Person Keypoint Detection Baselines with Keypoint R-CNN R50-FPN

How do I do hyperparameter tuning with the model above? Which files do I have to open?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use "config" to tune your model. Here is an official tutorial how you can use it (https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/configs.html)

And here is the file of all hyperparameters that you can tune (https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/detectron2/config/defaults.py)